# How to simulate a random unitary matrix with the condition that each entry is a complex number with the absolute value 1 in matlab

Tags: matrices, matlab, random-matrices

I have a code to create a random unitary matrix. However is it possible to get an unitary matrix in which the absolute value of each element is one ?

```
clear all
close all

%define a random matrix
R=randn(512,512)+1i*randn(512,512);
[U V]=svd(R); %performing SVD
% T=exp(1i*rand(512,512));
T=U; %required unitary matrix
```

Comment: Why not just create a random unitary matrix and then divide each entry by its absolute value?

Comment: I tried it but the resulting matrix won't be unitary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For all $z \in \mathbb C - \{0\}$:

$|\frac{z}{|z|}| = 1$

Divide each entry by its modulus.

Comment: I tried it but the resulting matrix won't be unitary anymore